# Keep the end of the path at a fixed height

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I a [nice example](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1642989#file-index-html) by Mike Bostock, a smooth D3 path transition is presented. See it running [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hzyxaez0/). The main function there is the following:

```
function tick() {

  // push a new data point onto the back
  data.push(random());

  // redraw the line, and slide it to the left
  path
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)
    .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
      .each("end", tick);

  // pop the old data point off the front
  data.shift();

}
```

I am trying to figure out how to write a variation of that script, in which the end of the line is always at a fixed height (say, at 0).

My first attempt was to update the `translate()` function there, like that:

```
var delta = y(0) - y(data[data.length-2]);  // or -1?.
...
.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + "," + delta + ")")
```

but the result was extremely bumpy. Any idea if there's a quick fix to my attempt, or any other simple way to achieve this goal?

Comment: I'm not familiar with d3.js, but I'm trying to understand your question: the idea is that the line gets fixed on a Y value, when it reaches X = 0? Let's say, you want the line to end on (0, 0) every tick? If so, the graph will not be only a right to left animation, you would have to slide the line up and down as well.

Comment: Well, actually I thought that the line will end up on (35, 0) every tick in this particular example... I think of the right edge of the chart as its "end". It may be also a bit more challenging that way... but your assumptions about the animation are probably correct.

Comment: Still playing with the code, manage to understand a bit more. Everytime the tick is called, the transform is reset .attr("transform", null), that's what is causing bumpyness on Y movement. This does not happen on X because you remove the element on data[0] and next time the graph will be already in place. I'm trying to think on a way to preserve Y coordinate between the calls.